# Python concatenate two columns but maintain fix length

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

I have a DataFrame as below. I want to concatenate first 2 columns.

- If the length of their concatenation is `<13` then I would like to add 0s in between so that the length becomes 13.
- If the length of their concatenation is `>=13` then I just want to concatenate.

---

```
d = {'col1': [123456, 2, 1234567], 'col2': [1234567, 4, 1234567]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
df['var3'] = df.col1.astype(str) + df.col1.astype(str)
df
```

In case of second row, instead of '22' I want 11 0s between 2 and 2. 
I would like to keep the third row as it is as the length of concatenation is `>13`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to convert the numbers to strings before doing anything else, so I assume that `col1` and `col2` are strings.

First, find the combined string lengths and how many zeros are missing:

```
pads = 13 - (df.col1.str.len() + df.col2.str.len())
```

Then generate the necessary paddings and concatenate the columns and the paddings:

```
df['var3'] = df.col1 + pads.apply(lambda x: x * '0') + df.col2
#0     1234561234567
#1     2000000000004
#2    12345671234567
```

Answer (score 1):

For each row, make a tuple with 3 values:

string1

string2

The difference between the length of both strings and 13 (or whatever target length)

```
x = pd.Series(list(zip(df['col1'].astype(str),
                       df['col2'].astype(str),
                       13 - (df['col1'].astype(str) + df['col2'].astype(str)).str.len())))
```

Then use the string method `ljust` to pad the left string with 0s and add it to the right string. Assign everything to the new column.

```
df['var3'] = x.apply(lambda x: x[0].ljust(x[2], '0') + x[1])
```

Comment: `.str.len()` is _much_ faster than `.apply(len)`. `.apply` is a very slow method and should be avoided at any cost.